# TROUBLE WITH CURL PROXY: Is my code working?

Tags: php, curl, xampp

Good day! I am having trouble using proxies on my **PHP script**. Can anyone help me?

**My code:**

```
<?php
function proxies()
{
  $proxylist = file("proxy.txt");
  $randomproxy = rand(0, sizeof($proxylist) - 1);
  $proxylist = $proxylist[$randomproxy];
  return $proxylist;
}
$ch = curl_init();
$proxy = proxies();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ifconfig.me/ip');
$ip = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $ip;
?>
```

I am using **XAMPP** to view my script, but whenever I try to test it. I will just encounter a result of a blank page. But whenever I try this **code**:

```
<?php
function proxies()
{
  $proxylist = file("proxy.txt");
  $randomproxy = rand(0, sizeof($proxylist) - 1);
  $proxylist = $proxylist[$randomproxy];
  return $proxylist;
}
$ch = curl_init();
$proxy = proxies();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '123.456.78.90:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ifconfig.me/ip');
$ip = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $ip;
?>
```

It will perfectly work, I am wondering if there is something wrong with my function, but whenever I tried to `echo $proxy` it will show me a proxy from the list, so I am really confused where did I go wrong.

**I am really grateful if you guys will help me. Thank you!**

Comment: can you show me your proxy.txt file so that i can test it in my laptop

Comment: @NalinNishant Sure I will be glad to share it to you. Here! [ProxyList](https://pastebin.com/U1qEt1zX)

Comment: i solved your issue ... actually your both answer are wrong

Comment: i am posting answer in few mins

Comment: @NalinNishant I'm grateful! Thanks!

Comment: hey check my below answe and approve my if it solves your problem

Comment: check below answer i added more details

Comment: @NalinNishant I will try to test it now. Thanks! Mind telling me why you use var_dump?

Comment: I used var_dump to see what's its returning. The var_dump() function is used to dump information about a variable. This function displays structured information such as type and value of the given variable. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure. This function is also effective with expressions.

Comment: @NalinNishant Thank you! It's working now. If bool(false), it's okay?

Comment: no bool(false) mean your proxy not working

Comment: you will get something like this 14.29.255.230bool(true)

Comment: your 2 or 1 of the ip is not working from your .txt file so check and remove them

Comment: @NalinNishant I get it now thank you!

Comment: also, I modified my below code to know which IP is working or which are not

Comment: Also you can dynamically delete that ip if it returns bool false by adding some bunch of code ;-)

Comment: @NalinNishant Now I'm planning to do that, and test multiple ip's. Can you help me? :o

Comment: well I tested your above code... and its also right :-) the problem is due to your ip .txt file

Comment: @NalinNishant I see, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @NalinNishant Because of the port, that's why you exploded it.

Comment: @NalinNishant I can use str_replace to delete not working prox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a `CURLOPT_PROXYPORT` now shave all your proxies in txt file and then get the value from it and split it into port and IP then use its value in curl field.

```
     <?php
function proxies()
{
  $proxylist = file("proxy.txt");
  $randomproxy = rand(0, sizeof($proxylist) - 1);
  $proxylist = $proxylist[$randomproxy];
  $words = explode(':', $proxylist);
  return $words;
  //var_dump($words);
}
$proxy = proxies();
$ch = curl_init();
//var_dump($proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ifconfig.me/ip');
$ip = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(empty($ip)){
  echo 'IP not working remove it -'.$proxy[0];
}else{
  echo ' - Working';
}
// var_dump($ip);
?>
```

> tested on this ip successfully - `45.55.159.57:9359`